# Should I uninstall my antivirus after the windows update?

Tags: windows-update, uninstall, windows-defender, avast, malwarebytes

It seems that windows updated its antivirus with the anniversary update. I still have avast and malwarebytes installed. Should I uninstall any of these? I only have free versions of both

Comment: Hello. Do you know how to use antivirus?

Comment: How is that an answer?

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer. Although I'm not sure if he's asking for help, or asking if you understand how anti-virus software works.Common advice is to only have one anti-virus program installed.

Comment: @HerbWolfe - common advice, true, but Avast is designed to run alongside Defender & Malwarebytes free version is designed to run alongside both. Actually, I'm going to throw this up there as an answer...

Comment: That was a question, placed in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: So you previously had all of them running.  Then you upgraded or updated Windows, which left a newer version of Defender?  So now you're asking if the new Defender is good enough that you don't need the others anymore if the free versions of those don't add benefit to the new Defender?

Answer (score 0):

Avast is designed to run alongside Defender & Malwarebytes free version is designed to run alongside both.

Windows Defender is considered the basic bare minimum needed to even vaguely protect a computer. So long as both Avast & Malwarebytes are kept up to date, they will do a better job than Defender alone.
Malwarebytes free, of course needs to be run manually, recommended once a week.